# Showing time markers on track on map in QGIS

Tags: qgis

If I have data from a vehicle with datetime, X, Y in CSV or similar format, can I load this as a vector (obviously yes so far), but then print the tracks with time tick markers every 10 minutes, and minor ticks every minute, for example?

I am using QGIS.

I want to show a route map, giving hints as to where to search for time tagged video and still images.

It was a feature that was easy to do with Oasis Montaj.

Comment: And whast exactly is your question? You want to know how to style some of your points based on a datetime field? Can you add a screenshot that shows how your result should look like? And best also provide a sample of your data. In any case, you should provide more details, otherwise it's just guessing - but what we might imagine is not what you need.

Comment: I want to plot my vehicle track as a line, obviously following the position that it drove, I want the line to have tickmarks at set time intervals and those tickmarks to have the time annotated.

Comment: As far as I understand, you ask about three different things: 1) how to connect the points to create a line? 2) How to interpolate time on this line? 3) How to create a tick marker symbol at these points? For 1: Use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Points to Path`. For 2 and 3, I advice to ask separate questions or update the initial question.

Comment: Sorry, to be clearer, pt 1 I know.  If my data is sampled at say 4Hz and I have times 09:59:59.231, 09:59:59:.481, 09:59:59.731, 09:59:59.981, 10:00:00.231 is there a standard library or plug in that can give a tick labelled and interpolated at 10:00:00 as "10:00". minor ticks at 10:02, 10.04, etc and a major tick labelled 10:10?

Comment: Please add this additional information to the initial question to increase chances to get an answer. You can edit the question for that.